# Create "Pull request" in Sourcetree for Gitlab

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I tried to create `pull request` in Sourcetree, but it asked me to set Remote Project Configuration. To set remote configurations, I searched through internet, and found [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-do-I-configure-a-pull-request-in-source-tree/qaq-p/1860). It said, it supports Stash, BitBucket and GitHub.

My question is, is there any possibility to create `pull requests` in Sourcetree for the remote, Gitlab? If Yes, how to do enable pull request for Gitlab in Sourcetree?

Comment: I saw in same [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-do-I-configure-a-pull-request-in-source-tree/qaq-p/1860) that, attasian didnt gave possibility to create `pull requests` for Gitlab. So is there any other way to create `pull requests` for Gitlab via Sourcetree?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the relevant Jira in,

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1845?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

and you can create a Merge Request instead of PR by following,

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html

Comment: This has changed recently: https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2018/08/29/sourcetree-3-0-branches-out-with-new-hosting-services/ However, I couldn't found a direct way to integrate gitlab into sourcetree.. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can go to your gitlab web instance, where you would normally create a merge request, such as this:

`https://gitlab.mydomain.com/web/nushopweb/merge_requests`

Copy the url and set it as a Stash type host with `#` or `?` appended so that SourceTree doesn't redirect you to a 404 page.

[image]

Then, when you press "Create pull request...", it will open a browser window with gitlab's merge requests and if you have just pushed your branch, it will immediately allow you to create a pull request.

The resulting URL might look like this, which is perfectly OK as the part after `#` is somewhat "ignored".

`https://gitlab.mydomain.com/web/nushopweb/merge_requests#/projects/web/repos/nushopweb/pull-requests?create&sourceBranch=feature%2fq%2f77523_wishlist-page`

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://github.com/JCID/sourcetree-custom-action-gitlab-merge-request-opener) a custom action setup, which will help to install a shortcut for opening a merge request in Gitlab.

Copy-pasting the contents, just in case this disappears one day:

---

> **Installation**
>
> `composer global require jcid/sourcetree-merge-request-opener`

File **sourcetree-merge-request-opener**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

foreach (array(__DIR__ . '/../../autoload.php', __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php', __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php') as $file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
        break;
    }
}

$repoPath  = $argv[1];
$iniConfig = parse_ini_file(
    sprintf(
        '%s/.git/config',
        $repoPath
    ),
    true
);
$repoUrl   = $iniConfig['remote origin']['url'];
$repoUrl   = str_replace(
    [':', 'git@', '.git',],
    ['/', 'https://', '/'],
    $repoUrl
);

$openCommand = sprintf('open "%smerge_requests/new?merge_request[force_remove_source_branch]=1&merge_request[source_branch]="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) -a "Google Chrome"', $repoUrl);
exec($openCommand);
```

Then inside SourceTree navigate to Preferences -> Custom Actions -> "Add" a new custom action:

[image]

> Now you can easily open a Gitlab merge request from the current branch with the set shortcut `⌘ =`